# Probability calculation of coinciding

Tags: probability

I'm wondering how to perform probability calculations for a situation like the following:

In a group $A$ of $200$ people in which there is another smaller group $A1$ of $10$ people, what is the probability of getting $2$ people from group $A1$ when choosing $2$ people randomly from group $A$?

Thanks

Comment: Well, what's the total; number of ways of choosing two people from group A? What's the number of ways of getting two people from A1? What should you then do with those two numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking about sampling without replacement. Immediately, two different approaches to this problem come to mind. First, we could think about it probabilistically. Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ denote the events that the first and second people you sample are from the smaller group respectively.

It should be clear that $P(E_1) = \frac{10}{200}$. Further, we have a conditional probability for $E_2$, particularly, $P(E_2 \mid E_1) = \frac{9}{199}$. Hence, the overall probability is

$$ P(E_1) \cdot P(E_2 \mid E_1) = \frac{10}{200} \cdot \frac{9}{199} \approx 
0.0022 $$

Alternatively, you could take a more combinatorial approach. There $\binom{200}{2}$ equally likely ways to choose 2 people from 200 people. Of these, $\binom{10}{2}$ consist of pairs from the smaller group. Hence, the probability is

$$ \frac{\binom{10}{2}}{\binom{200}{2}} = \frac{10! \cdot 198!}{8! \cdot 200!} = \frac{10 \cdot 9}{199 \cdot 200} \approx 0.0022$$